# Did Adam and Eve have children in paradise?

Tags: old-testament, genesis, creation, adam-and-eve, eden

I was just reading the account of Adam and Eve in the NIV 84 and it doesn't really say they didn't.

The Bible does mention when Sarah had her first boy. When Mary had her first son. But not really when Eve had her first son. Does it?

I'm just wondering because I have in my mind that they had children after they got kicked out. Partly because of the common belief. What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long was it before Adam and Eve sinned?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5299/how-long-was-it-before-adam-and-eve-sinned)

Comment: Actually, I may retract that close vote because we could tighten things up.

Comment: It would be good to have an answer to this on the basis of the doctrine of original sin or federal headship. I think one or both of them would mean that there couldn't have been any children before the fall or else the fall wouldn't have been universal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The crux of this question is really [How long was it before Adam and Eve sinned?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/5299/how-long-was-it-before-adam-and-eve-sinned)

The biblical record only has the following facts:

- Adam and Eve's first child was Cain, and the second Abel, by virtue of Genesis 4.
- Genesis 4 also suggests that Seth was not born until after Cain killed Abel, an act that could not have occurred in the Garden.
- Genesis 5 says that Adam was 130 when Seth was born, so that establishes an upper limit for the length of the time on the garden.  (I will repeat my assertion that had I been Eve, I only would have lasted about 32 minutes before getting kicked out, nonetheless I digress.)

This means that the only two children who could have been born in the Garden are Cain and Abel.

Circumstantially, I would have to suggest that the evidence would make a much stronger case for the children being born after rather than before:

1. There is no mention of anyone other than Adam or Eve being cast out.  (And the [Lillith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lilith) thing is just Jewish legend.)
2. The fact that the narrative records the conception of Cain after Genesis 3 gives no reason to suspect it happened before.

Comment: Just to add to this great answer, Genesis 4:1  And Adam knew Eve his wife; and she conceived, and bare Cain, and said, I have gotten a man from the LORD. And we must remember that Eve's punishment for their disobedience was:  Gen 3:16  Unto the woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception; in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to thy husband, and he shall rule over thee. That was pronounced by God at their expulsion.

Comment: +1 for preferring common sense to speculations that produce paradoxical problems.

Answer (score 1):

No they did not, here is the timeline as I see it:

**The commandments:**

> Genesis 1:28 And God blessed them, and God said unto them, Be fruitful, and multiply, and replenish the earth, and subdue it: and have dominion over the fish of the sea, and over the fowl of the air, and over every living thing that moveth upon the earth.
>
> Genesis 2:16-17 And the Lord God commanded the man, saying, Of every tree of the garden thou mayest freely eat: But of the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, thou shalt not eat of it: for in the day that thou eatest thereof thou shalt surely die.

**Consequence for Breaking the 2nd commandment:**

> Genesis 3:23 Therefore the Lord God sent him forth from the garden of Eden, to till the ground from whence he was taken.

**The children come:**

> Genesis 4:1 And Adam knew Eve his wife; and she conceived, and bare Cain, and said, I have gotten a man from the Lord.

Answer (score 0):

They were removed from the garden before any children were born.  Eve named her first child to reflect his birth when she said (obviously paraphased) ' I have gotten a child with the help of God'.   She was making reference to God's curse of her after the fall.  Also, it says after they were kicked out of the garden, Adam knew his wife Eve.  Plus, Cain killed Abel and committed sin because of his sinful nature. This would not have been possible until after Adam and Eve's fall from grace.

Comment: Source? Are you suggesting that they didn't have sex prior to being kicked out either? That seems highly unlikely. Affable at least makes his inferences clear. You've made a truth statement with no backup here.

Answer (score 0):

My belief is this-how many times does God have to command something or for that matter even say something for it to be true? Gen:1:28 God said " be fruitful and multiply" whitch was His first order to Adam and Eve. The sin of disobedience that violated Gods command was the act of taking from the tree of knowledge of good and evil. God told Eve He would greatly increase her pain in child birth; how do you increase something that she had never experienced? Adam named his wife Eve because she was the mother of all the living: Cain and Able hadn't been born yet. In Luke Adam is referred to as the son of God. Adam was created in Gods image and was sinless in his nature and so was Eve. If children were born in the garden they would have been sinless in nature also because man had not violated Gods Law yet. In Gen:6 the scripture said that the sons of God saw the daughters of men and they were beautiful and they wanted them. What could be a better answer than this for Gods disgust with man kind because pure hearted children and children with a fallen sin nature had cohabited and produce an offspring that offended God.look at Gen:6:3 and 4 then Gen:5,6 and 7 make sence. What kind of person would these double natured creatures have been and what would their children have been because they were the offspring of a pure hearted father and a mother with a fallen sin nature. Also this answers where Cain got his wife and why God destroyed all humanity. Gen.6:13 said the end of all flesh has come befour Me,and Noah found favor in the eye of The Lord, Gen.7:1

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. I was following you until about half way through. Perhaps you can [edit] this to clear it up a bit. It reads more like notes than a proper answer. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: interesting thoughts but wouldn't the sons of God be still among us? They were immortal so they should be  still alive but it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 0):

The question should be hinged on the first command given to mankind (be fruitful amd multiple) and then the question is begged, how long were they in the garden being obedient. Another situation that begs the question about children is: who was Cain afraid of? In the curse pronounced against Eve, God said that her pain in child bearing will be multiples, you only multiple that which is known. I personally believe that child bearing was taking place in the garden for an untold amount of time, I support this position with Romans 5:12-13 which states that all men did not sin, but rather sin spread throughout the world by he act of Adam. It took nearly a thousand years for sin to reach its pinnacle at the flood, but keep in mind there were still sinless people, such as Enoch who was translated to be with he Lord. In the end you have to decide what he evidence and inferences point toward.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, I look forward to good studies, questions and answers with the community

Answer (score -1):

I think they could have had many children in the Garden. However, Cain's arrival seems to fit in with what Eve thought to be a prophetic promise that the seed of the woman will bruise the head of the serpant. In that prophecy Gen. 3:15 "And I will put enmity between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise ***his*** heel." Hence Cain's envy of Abel's sacrifice being accepted and his being rejected. Eve might have had an inadvertant hand in the death of Abel. So if there was a family living in paradise and sinless their sinlessness would not have lasted long due to Adam sinning they would have all fallen because sin had entered the world. I think when we read about Cain and Abel this is a whole different chapter of human history apart from the garden.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. On this site, we're not looking for personal interpretation, but rather focusing on what various Christian groups teach.  See [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)